# No update for externalized tikz figure because of font change?

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, fontspec

There is something fishy going on here and i have no clue why. So please, help me to understand the issue and thx in advance.

My problem: no update for tikz figure (see MWE) with specified font by fontspec respectively a working update but under the condition of no font change. And for both cases i do not get any log messages or errors.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec-luatex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

% comment out only the line below, change anything within the tikz environment and the MWE works as intended
\setmainfont{Calibri} 

\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/force remake}


\begin{document}
test text

\tikzsetnextfilename{myTest}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
    (0,1) coordinate (a) node[right] {$ a1 $}
--  (1,0) coordinate (b) node[left] {b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Background: originally i wanted to synchronize the mainfont (STIX) with the mathfont (XITS), which was necessary because of to many variables.

Comment: Welcome! Are you saying Calibri is essential to reproduce the problem? (I don't have Calibri, so I can't test in that case.) If I comment out the Calibri line and compile twice, without changes, the externalised image is recompiled on the second run, as expected.

Comment: There's always a log, even if it isn't very interesting. In my case, I get two log files per compilation (one for my test file and one for `myTest`).

Comment: **First** of all: yes, there are logs (mea culpa), but they were not displayed by TeXstudio. However, after deleting everything in the folder and new compiling (twice) i got "_! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e_". Therefore i tried to add '\RequirePackage{shellesc}', which had no effect.


**Second**: no, Calibri as well as Arial, Tahoma or _you-name-it_ resulted in the same non-existing externalized figure.

Comment: That's the beginning of an error, but not a complete error. What compilation command are you using? I used `lualatex -shell-escape <filename>.tex`. Does externalisation fail even on the first compilation?

Comment: My compilation command would be `lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode %.tex`. And yes, it did.

Comment: If it fails even on the first compilation, the problem isn't the picture not being updated. Is the external file ever written at all? You said it worked when you commented out the font change and altered the picture. Do you get `myTest.pdf` produced in that case? Try running `lualatex` interactively if you can. (Sorry, I know nothing about Windows, but this would mean removing `interaction=batchmode` and running it from a command line.)